# If $A$ is injective and $\text{Im}(A) = Y$, then $A$ is invertible.

Tags: linear-transformations, banach-spaces

I am studying *A Primer Nonlinear Analysis* of A.Ambrosetti and there is something I do not understand in the second chapter. He said that the following result is a consequence of the *Closed Graph Theorem*.

> Let $A \in L(X, Y)$ be a continuous linear map between two Banach spaces. If $A$ is injective and $\text{Im}(A) = Y$, then $A$ is invertible.

Why do we need the closed graph theorem to prove this result ? Injectivity and surjectivity is not enough to show the inversibility of $A$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also have to show that $A^{-1}:Y \to X$ is a bounded linear operator.

This is a consequence of the open mapping theorem.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the author meant that $A$ is invertible **and continuous**. This is why he leverages the closed graph theorem.